# Can't call object's method

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Ok. Now i move that Translation class to seperate place Translation.java.
But still i can t use that:

```
Translation translation = new Translation();
    translation.Translate("sadfas",);//this not work??
```

class and method is public. Why i cant use that???

I am very new to Java and Android.
I have an OcrCaptureActity. Inside that activity I have a class like this:

```
public class Translation {

    public String mytext;

    public String translate (String str) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue( getApplicationContext());
        String url ="someurl";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        //mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                        mytext = response;
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);

        return mytext;
    }
}
```

In my OcrGraphic class I have a useage like that:

```
OcrCaptureActivity.Translation translation = new OcrCaptureActivity().new Translation();
translation.translate("dfas"); //that translate method not work. It s red.
```

Any idea what s the problem. 
I have only one reason to use Translate class in the activity is that line only works in activity.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue( getApplicationContext());//this only works inside activity
```

Otherwise I can t use something like this in a normal class:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue( this);//it gives error
```

So if you can help about how I can Translation object's translate method or how can I initialized RequestQueue in some class other than activity 
That will be very helpfull for me.

Comment: `new OcrCaptureActivity().new Translation();` this syntax does not look correct...

Comment: `    translation.Translate("sadfas",);//this not work?? What is this? I have never developed android application but i am ok with  java. You have function `translate` what is `Translate`?
`

Comment: @Luai Ghunim i didn t care about syntax while writing here. It s correct in the app but i cant call that function.

Comment: Well , if you write here `translation.Translate("sadfas",);``this will not work for sure btw there is no reason that you can't call that function. If you write `translation.translate("sadfas",);` it will work for sure.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim But it not work. It saying translate cannot resolve symbol translate

Comment: 'I cannot use' and 'this not work??' are not problem descriptions. The error message you have just quoted says 'translate' but your code says `translation.Translate()` the first time and `translation.translate()` the second time. Which is it? Java is case-sensitive you know.

Comment: You really have to care about what you write here as it matters. Copy the relevant parts verbatim so we know what *exactly* you're doing. Forget formulations like "this not work", there's an error message somewhere and it belongs to the question.

Answer (score -1):

> I tried to move that translate method where i will use in the class.
>   But I just need to know how can that line work?
>   Volley.newRequestQueue( this);

This line of code assumes that the call is made from inside an activity. In this situation, the activity is referenced by `this` which is passed as an argument to `Volley.newRequestQueue()`.

If the line is just copied and pasted in some other class which is not an Activity or Context, it won't work, as `this` won't be referencing an activity.

The solution for such situation is to get a reference to the activity that is running and pass that as an argument instead of `this`.

To have the Translation class outside of the Activity class, you can add a Context paramenter to the method, and pass the activity together with the string when you use it.

You would call `translation.translate("dfas", activity);`where activity is the activity from where the translation is running (from the activity itself you would pass it like `this`).

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AnotherClass anotherClass = new AnotherClass(this); //this is the activity
        anotherClass.runMeToTranslate("The text to be translated");
    }
}
```

**AnotherClass.java**

```
/* Here we use the translation class */
public class AnotherClass{
    Context context;

    public AnotherClass(Context ctx){
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public runMeToTranslate(String text){
        Translation translation = new Translation();
        translation.translate(text,context);

    }

}
```

**Translation.java**

```
public class Translation {

    public String mytext;



    public String translate (String str, final Context ctx){

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue( ctx.getApplicationContext());
        String url ="someurl";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        //mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                        mytext = response;
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);

        return mytext;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to move that translate method where i will use in the class. But I just need to know how can that line work in a class?this only works in activiy.  Volley.newRequestQueue( this); // it says volley cant applied to .... By the way i don t wanna call translate method in the activity. I wanna call it in the other class

Comment: In Android the main class of your app is most likely an Activity, from that class, 'this' is an instance of your Activity.

Comment: i don t know how to get an instance of activity ? @Juan